# Как правильно хранить пароль с солью в БД?

Tags: c#, база-данных, хеширование, хранение-данных, пароль

Разбираюсь с хешированием и хранением паролей. Возникла следующая проблема: в БД у меня таблица, где в нескольких колонках будет храниться захешированные пароли, и соответственно, если хранить уникальную соль с отдельном поле, нужно создать для каждой колонки юзеров свою колонку с солью. Можно ли хранить и соль и пароль юзера в 1 поле БД(если можно то каким образом?) или так делать плохо?
И еще правильно ли я понял: соль хранится в БД в незахешированном виде?

Comment: соль в виде хэша в одной колонке, пароль в виде хэша в другой...........а вообще, вроде этот способ как устарел давно....... есть в языках вроде расширения для хэширования пароля более взломостойчивыми паролями ипри этом без всякой соли (во всяком случае в PHP есть )))

Comment: Ну вообще насколько я знаю, если данные можно разделить по таблицам то нужно делить, поэтому я бы наверное создал отдельную таблицу для соли и хэшированного пароля а в юзере хранил бы ссылку на поле в таблице с паролем.

Comment: Можно, все так делают

Comment: @АлексейШиманский «без всякой соли» — всё с точностью до наоборот, пхпшный password_hash по умолчанию использует солёный bcrypt

Comment: а каким образом тогда соль из хэшированной версии приводится к оригинальному виду чтобы захешировать с ней пароль при входе пользователя и сравнить с тем, что есть в БД? Или это не так работает?

Comment: @andreymal окей, может не так выразился. имел в виду без хранения в БД ещё всяких солей или доп колонок для супермегашифрования)

Comment: @Stanislavoo по какому-нибудь разделителю — знаку доллара, двоеточию, ну или тупо объявить соль постоянной длины и вытаскивать её из колонки по нужному числу символов (насколько я понял, именно так делает пхпшный password_hash)

Comment: а если например вытягивать соль из каких-то данных пользователя(даже например из хэша логина или что-то подобное) и тогда ее можно будет даже не хранить нигде. такой способ используется сейчас?

Comment: [Hash passwords in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing?view=aspnetcore-7.0). Читать весь раздел Data Protection.

Comment: [Adding Salt to Hashing: A Better Way to Store Passwords](https://auth0.com/blog/adding-salt-to-hashing-a-better-way-to-store-passwords/) - хорошая статья, где объясняется, зачем же нужна соль.